# Does anyone know of an academic reference for this proof that the tangent to a hyperbola at a point bisects the angle between each focus to the point?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, conic-sections

I am writing a report and as part of it I need to prove the property that for a point $P$ on a hyperbola, the tangent to the hyperbola at $P$ bisects the angle $\angle F_1PF_2$ where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the foci of the hyperbola.

Wikipedia has the following proof which is pretty neat but obviously doesn't constitute an academic reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#The_tangent_bisects_the_angle_between_the_lines_to_the_foci

Does anybody know of any books or papers which use the same proof?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the references given in the Wikipedia article?

Answer (score 5):

This is the "reflection property" of the hyperbola. In the context of "academic references", it is good practice to cite the original source, which is

• [Apollonius of Perga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius_of_Perga), 200 BCE, *Treatise on Conic Sections*, book III, proposition 48; [English translation](https://www.wilbourhall.org/millionbookspdfs/treatiseonconics00apolrich.pdf) by T.L. Heath, page 116 (Cambridge University Press, 1896).

Alternatively, you may prefer a more recent proof, so here is one:

• Michael K. Brozinsky, *Reflection Property of the Ellipse and the Hyperbola*, The College Mathematics Journal, Vol. 15, No. 2 (1984), pp. 140-142.
https://doi.org/10.2307/2686519